# CSS just for most basic HTML

Tags: css, resources

I've read that my note system Wikidpad, which exports to very simple HTML, can use CSS (http://wikidpad.sourceforge.net/help/HtmlCss.html)
The elements in the output are not more than basic headings, bullet points and tables.

I'd like to try some kind of improved style, but I as I have no knowledge about CSS, so the best I can do is to save some Myfile.css to a directory :) However if I google "CSS template" I get all sorts of complicating results that I cannot make sense of :( Am I using wrong terminology?

Can you suggest what I should search for or maybe you even know a ressource where a get a simple CSS file with some decent standard HTML elements. I do not wish to make custom adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

W3 Schools is a great resource and here is a direct link to their CSS Tutorial to get you started. [CSS Tutorial](http://w3schools.com/css/default.asp) Basically you can copy and paste the CSS style once your comfortable after using W3 Schools preview option, copy and paste your custom style into your myfile.css and save it.

Comment: Actually it isn't! Read this: http://w3fools.com/. w3.org is a **real** great resource.